# Are these statements equivalent (static variables, const variables, and generics)

Tags: c++, g++, clang

So I am writing a custom smooth-step function that allows me to edit the amount of smoothing.

Essentially with low factors the smooth-step is practically linear but with high factors there is a large curve.

The code to do this is as follows:

```
float smoothstep(float x, float factor) {
    float c = 0.5f / ((1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-factor))) - 0.5f);
    return c * ((1.0f / (1.0 + exp(-factor * (2.0f * x - 1.0f)))) - 0.5f) + 0.5;
}
```

Now since this method will get called a few thousand times a frame I am trying to optimize it so that c is calculated at runtime. I am hoping the compiler can do this because I am passing in a finite amount of factors. So the variable passed in for factor will always be written in eg `smoothstep(x, 1.0)`. As of now I will actually pass in one factor.

So I rewrote the function like this to use a generic parameter

```
template <int F>
float smoothstep(float x) {
    const float factor = (float)F / 100.0;
    static const float c = 0.5f / ((1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-factor))) - 0.5f);
    return c * ((1.0f / (1.0 + exp(-factor * (2.0f * x - 1.0f)))) - 0.5f) + 0.5;
}
```

This is rather un-ideal since you can only use integers as template parameters and thus I have to pass in an int that is 100x what I actually need it to be. That being said I believe this solution will cause the compiler to pre-compute factor and c. Right?

Now my question **is there a way to do this without generics** here are two stabs I took at this

```
float smoothstep(float x, float factor) {
    const float c = 0.5f / ((1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-factor))) - 0.5f);
    return c * ((1.0f / (1.0 + exp(-factor * (2.0f * x - 1.0f)))) - 0.5f) + 0.5;
}
```

and

```
float smoothstep(float x, float factor) {
    static const float c = 0.5f / ((1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-factor))) - 0.5f);
    return c * ((1.0f / (1.0 + exp(-factor * (2.0f * x - 1.0f)))) - 0.5f) + 0.5;
}
```

My hope is that that in one of these cases the pre-compiler (both Clang and G++) see these and precompute c for each of the finite factors I pass in.

My understanding is that `const` is a keyword used to signal the pre-compiler and compiler that a variable will not be changed and thus it should consider optimizations for it as such.

I also think that `static` on a scoped variable will suggest to the compiler that the variable belongs to the function and thus have the compiler precompute it and include it in the functions definition per factor.

However I am very skeptical that my understanding of `const` and `static` is right so I am therefore guessing that neither of those definitions pre-compute c. What am I getting wrong? Is there a non-generic way to get the pre-compiler to pre-compute c?

Comment: Make the function inline and make sure you have optimizations turned on?

Comment: Is `inline` just a way to signal the compiler to pre-process such that code like `int add(int x, int y) {return x + y}int a = add(b, c)` is pre-processed into `int a = b+c` essentially removing the scope?

Comment: Nope. The `static` keyword, as used here, will horribly screw everything up. The first call to the function will initialize the static variable. Congratulations! This static variable will now keep this value no matter what `factor` is, on subsequent calls to this function!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what about the just const version?

Comment: A compiler is allowed  to implement any optimization that the compiler can prove has no observable side-effects. However the compiler is not required to do that, and there is no guarantee that it will be sophisticated enough to inline the function call and determine that the calculation of `c` can be done only one time for all consecutive calls to this function that pass in the same `factor`. The best opportunity to help the compiler figure it out is to restructure so that `factor` is computed separately by a `constexpr` function, and passed in as a parameter to `smoothstep`().

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function `inline` (which also means the function should be in a header file) and make sure you have optimizations on.

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/rztmWe - as you can see there is only one call to `exp`.

Unfortunately for you, I don't think there's a guaranteed way to get this effect - you'll have to rely on compiler optimizations. On the other hand, a lot of compiler optimizations are fairly reliable these days.

Comment: Does the generic solution do that too? And when you say the function needs to be in the header do you mean its implementation too?

Comment: @J.Doe [Generic solution also does that](https://godbolt.org/z/A3nUI-). Yes, the implementation. The implementation also has to be in the header for the generic solution. (Otherwise the compiler can't see the definition of the function, so it's certainly not going to generate special versions of it if it doesn't know what it does)